# Trying to set a repeating alarm from a PreferenceFragment but not working. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-alarms, preferencefragment

So I have a settings fragment that extends to the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` inside the main activity of my android app that can setup has a switch to turn on alarm. However, the repeating alarm is not working and I'm not quite sure why.

Here is the code for some of the related methods in my fragment that I call:

```
override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
    if (key == USERNAME){
        val username = sharedPreferences.getString(USERNAME, DEFAULT_VALUE)
        usernamePreference.summary = username
    }
    if (reminderPreference.isChecked){
        saveReminder(true,sharedPreferences)
        alarmReceiver.setRepeatingAlarm(fragmentContext,"RepeatingAlarm","01:20","Github reminder")
    } else {
        saveReminder(false,sharedPreferences)
        alarmReceiver.cancelAlarm(fragmentContext)
    }
}

private fun saveReminder(state: Boolean,sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences) {
    val settingsPreference = SettingsPreference(fragmentContext)
    settings = SettingsModel()
    settings.reminder = state
    settings.username = sharedPreferences.getString(USERNAME,DEFAULT_VALUE)
    settingsPreference.setSettings(settings)
}
```

Here are also some code from the `SettingsPreference` class:

```
internal class SettingsPreference(context: Context){
companion object{
    private const val PREFS_NAME = "settings_pref"
    private const val USERNAME_KEY = "username"
    private const val REMINDER_KEY = "switch_preference"
}

private val preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

fun setSettings(value: SettingsModel){
    val editor = preferences.edit()
    editor.putString(USERNAME_KEY,value.username)
    editor.putBoolean(REMINDER_KEY,value.reminder)
    editor.apply()
}

fun getSettings(): SettingsModel{
    val model = SettingsModel()
    model.username = preferences.getString(USERNAME_KEY,"username")
    model.reminder = preferences.getBoolean(REMINDER_KEY,false)
    return model
}
```

}

The full code can be seen in my github repository: https://github.com/briancatraguna/GitHubClone

UPDATE:
Maybe its because of my fragment context that is causing the problem?

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
    init()
    setSummaries()
}

private fun init(){
    USERNAME = resources.getString(R.string.key_username)
    usernamePreference = findPreference<EditTextPreference>(USERNAME) as EditTextPreference

    LANGUAGE = resources.getString(R.string.language)
    languageSettings = findPreference<Preference>(LANGUAGE) as Preference

    REMINDER = resources.getString(R.string.switch_preference)
    reminderPreference = findPreference<SwitchPreference>(REMINDER) as SwitchPreference

    alarmReceiver = AlarmReceiver()

    fragmentContext = activity?.applicationContext!!
    fragmentContext.registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, IntentFilter())
    val settingsPreference = SettingsPreference(fragmentContext)
    if (settingsPreference.getSettings().reminder){
        reminderPreference.isChecked = true
    } else {
        reminderPreference.isChecked = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered ``AlarmReceiver`` somewhere? It's not in your manifest, so you'd need to have called ``Context.registerReceiver()`` somewhere in your code: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @cactustictacs I have just registered it in my manifest. You can check out my last commit, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is ``onReceive`` firing in the ``AlarmReceiver`` class? You could do with some logging statements to say when a particular method fires, so you know what's happening and what isn't (or set some breakpoints and run the debugger). You need to track down the exact point where it's not doing what it's supposed to... Also, you're using a ``setInexact`` call to set the alarm - that allows the system to deliver the alarm at a different time if it's more convenient, could be wrong by several minutes! You should probably use one of the ``setExact`` calls while you're developing and testing your app